# axios: Cannot read property 'slice' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

Got this error while doing some react server side rendering with redux

Stack trace

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of null
    at dispatchHttpRequest (E:\Projects\real-estate\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:84:37)
    at httpAdapter (E:\Projects\real-estate\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:19:10)
    at dispatchRequest (E:\Projects\real-estate\node_modules\axios\lib\core\dispatchRequest.js:52:10)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

Action

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const FETCH_USER = 'FETCH_USER';
export const FETCH_POSTS = 'FETCH_POSTS';
const GET_POSTS_URI = '/api/posts';

export const fetchPosts = () => {
        let posts = axios.get(GET_POSTS_URI).catch(err => console.log(err));
        return {
            type: FETCH_POSTS,
            payload: posts
        }
}
```

API

```
app.get('/api/posts', function(req, res, next) {
    Post.model.find()
        .exec()
        .then(function(posts) {
            res.send(posts);
        }, function(err) {
            return next(err);
        });
})
```

I still got the JSON response in the network tab in dev tool, but I could not retrieve the JSON response in the reducers. I also didn't get this error when I used OpenWeatherAPI

Answer (score 0):

You are missing redux-thunk because you need it in order to do side-effect(like api call). Check out this: [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) and [redux async actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html).